# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/App.framework/App

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

While Flutter Run for IOS from Xcode I am getting this issue. I have search a lot but non of the solution is working to me. My issue on App.framework . I am not able to fine solution for this. I am struggling on this. Please guide me on this. I will post error which I am getting.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/App.framework/App   Referenced from:
>   /~/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9399EA4C-DDE3-4F6C-9CB9-A9D0194C2297/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A5F968E9-0E67-4037-AFB0-02C5E1E68841/Runner.app/Runner
>   Reason: image not found (lldb)

Thanks in advance

```
target Version 10.3  
Xcode Version 11.1
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue. Solution:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Solution:

1. I have deleted entire IOS folder inside flutter project
2. clean the project
3. install cocoa library again
4. install or update pods
5. finally build ios project for release
6. run the project

Issue fixed. Enjoy

Comment: Hi, I can't install any app on iPhone. I get a similar error but different ([post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59520593/flutter-signature-invalid-when-tried-on-an-ios-device)). I don't have a Podfile. Flutter doesn't generate it. Can you share yours to see an example?

Comment: If you don't have pod file navigate to ios folder location using terminal.  Then follow the given steps from step 3. It will create pod file in your project

Comment: You saved me for spending whole day on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your Runner -> Build Phases. Making sure that "App.framework" and "Flutter.framework" at the two place.

1. Link Binary With Libraries.
2. Embed Frameworks.

[image: Here's a screenshot of what I'm referring to]

Answer (score 0):

It's need update ruby-macho version. run script
`sudo gem update ruby-macho`

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92896

Answer (score 0):

I my case deintegrating and installing the pods solved my issue:

- cd into the ios path with the terminal/cmd
- pod deintegrate
- pod install

Since i had this issue about 2 days i share here some of the commands that i'm not sure if contributed to solve the issue:

- pod update --repo-update
- sudo gem update ruby-macho

Flutter clean, get and update (executed inside the flutter app directory)

- flutter clean
- flutter get
- flutter upgrade

Don't forget to execute the pod deintegrate/install after the commands.