# Not able to launch the flutter app on real device

Tags: flutter

I am trying to deploy app on a real device, so that I am just using the flutter project which count button clicks without changing anything.

IOS version: 13.3.1 (iPhone 8)

Mac version: 10.14.6 (Macbook air)

I have set the team to my apple id (personal team). I can run the app using emulator, and I can also install the app on my iPhone, but I can't launch it. I receive error like this on my computer:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1576AD84-3151-4C2B-A154-4990FBEAF366/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1576AD84-3151-4C2B-A154-4990FBEAF366/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1576AD84-3151-4C2B-A154-4990FBEAF366/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58948346/6804642)

Comment: Did you build the app before loading it on your phone? There are two versions debug (the one you can run hot restart and reload on) and release (the one that gives you a file to install)