# Flutter Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, flutter, frameworks, emulation, sigabrt

I am building a Flutter App and i get this error(Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) when i want to emulate it on Simulator ore a Real device and also in Build Configuration: Release and Debug.)

These are the more detailed Errors:

```
0x111410f7a <+10>: jae    0x111410f84               ; <+20>
0x1113b6025 <+37>: movq   -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
```

[image: Overview of my Xcode]

When i click the continue program execution button i get this:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

How can i resolve these errors?
Thanks for any help

Comment: LOOK AT YOUR STACK TRACE!  The *important* part is `library not loaded`!  SIGABRT is a *side effect*.  The "root cause" is that your application needs a library that the runtime couldn't find.  Fix the "missing library" problem!

Comment: In Android Studio i have no Problems so it means that there is something wrong with how the library's are implemented in the iOS code and not that i import the false library's in my flutter code, right? And thanks for your answer.

Comment: @paulsm4 I got this solution(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48035) but when i put ios. 13.4 in my runner target and runner project file it still doesn't work do you know a soulution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58948346/13638276

Delete and rebuild the iOS part of your Flutter App.